# Individual <> Contact Relationship

Tags: contact, gdpr, individual

I'd like to set up validation rule logic so that if Data Loader loads or updates a contact with the *same email* as an Individual with 'shouldForget' checked (on the Individual record), then throw an error.

The problem I've been running into is establishing a relationship, aside from the out of the box Individual lookup field that is created when I enabled the Individual object, which I placed on the Contact page layout.

When I'm creating a validation rule on the contact object I'm attempting to insert a field from the Individual object, but it's not available. See screen shot: [image: Expecting to see "Individual > ", much like I see "Account > "]

Expecting to see: "Individual > ", much like I see "Account > "

I know that the Individual object has some limited functionality in terms of automation, but I'm not sure why I can't pull fields from the Individual object onto the Contact for validation rules, custom fields, etc.

How can I pull Individual object fields onto the Contact object?